# Traveling Salesman Number of Possible Routes

Tags: np-complete, hamiltonian-path

My question is:

If there are 12 cities to visit, how many possible routes are?

Are there (11*10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1)/2 = 19,958,400 routes?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

The traveling salesman problem with $n$ cities has

$\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$

routes.

It is $(n-1)!$ instead of $n!$ because it does not matter in which city you start.

Comment: so with 19,958,400 routes ... and a computer calculating 10,000,000 routes per second .. it would take less than two seconds to it to evaluate every possible solution?

Comment: @user260648 Yes

Comment: $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$ why $1/2$ ?

Comment: @Anonymous Because of overcounting.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: E.g. $X, A, B, C, X$;

$X, C, B, A, X$ are considerd the same in the usual formulation of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, that is correct, but...

Why do you start with 11? The salesman has 12 cities to start with, so the product would have a 12* in the beginning.

Except if the question says 'starting in a given city', but then it's effectively a 11 city problem, not 12.

Comment: the question is: "starting from one of the locations" .. so then it begins with 11 right?

Comment: I don't see "starting from one of the locations" in the question. With that, it is correct.